# Doom: Return to previous buffer after kill-buffer?

Tags: buffers, doom

Recently switched to doom emacs and one behaviour I can't seem to get back is this:

1. In buffer A, open new file in buffer B
2. kill-buffer B (Cx-k)
3. Back in buffer A

Currently, after killing buffer B, it switches to another buffer but not always A. I want it to switch always to the previous buffer. I tried adding `(previous-buffer)` to `kill-buffer-hook` which did work but since this hook seems to be called all over the place, it had horrible side-effects. Any ideas?